# how to remove multiple cells that are empty in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet with a about 100 columns and close to 20,000 rows. Many cells are empty, about 10,000. Is there an automated way to remove all **empty cells** using VBA?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to shift other cells to up.. use this code in vba platform:

```
Sub test()
For x = 1 To 20000
For y = 1 To 100
If ActiveSheet.Cells(x, y).Text = "" Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(x, y).Delete
End If
Next
Next
End Sub
```

(This code checks every cell and delete it if it's empty)

Or if you want to shifts them to left, use this one:

```
Sub test()
For x = 1 To 20000
For y = 1 To 100
If ActiveSheet.Cells(x, y).Text = "" Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(x, y).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End If
Next
Next
End Sub
```

(This code checks every cell and delete it if it's empty, but it shift cells with instruction: `Shift:=xlToLeft` )

Comment: Why loop through 2m cells when you can use xlCellTypeBlanks? By looping through all the cells it will take like forever. What if he will have 500k rows?